# Php Regular Expression preg_match repeated characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string in php like this.

```
$string = "123451"
```

which contains non-consecutive repeated characters of `1`.
How do i match the repeated characters using preg_match.

I browsed around and found `preg_match('/(.)\1\1/', $string))` but it only works for repeated consecutive characters.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Im trying to achieve error check on the string which returns true if  repeated characters found. I allow strings like 1234,1245 and etc but not 1223, 1434..in another word i want every digit to appear only once. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like

```
(\d+).*\1
```

If you get any match there is a repeated number.

Comment: yes that works. thank you very much..
preg_match('/(\d+).*\1/', $string)

Comment: Why the plus?  Aren't we looking for any repeating character at all, not sequences of repeating chars?